# React - using "document" inside of a component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If i have a presentational (child) component with the following line:

```
<small id="parameters"> some parameters text </small>
```

I noticed that if i go to its parent container component and try to get that element by:

```
 const textElem = document.getElementById('parameters').value;
```

It is not going to get its value.

Why is that? If i use `document` in a component, is it only "local" to that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document` inside a component, to reference the global `document` object, it's not local to that component, however, at the point you're referencing `document.getElementById('parameters')` this element might not have been rendered yet to the dom, so make sure to call it after the child element has rendered.

On the other hand, maybe you meant to use: `document.getElementById('parameters').innerHTML` 
to get the text inside that element, instead of `.value`

Comment: yes, you can do that in `componentDidMount()` or in `useEffect()`

Comment: Yeah the child element has been rendered.
Should i then be able to use `textElem.select();`? Because currently it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: did you try document.getElementById('parameters').innerHTML ?

Comment: also document.getElementById('parameters').innerText

Comment: Yeah, i got `HTMLUnknownElement` which is weird because i'm viewing that child component so it was clearly rendered..

Comment: The fact that you are viewing it does not necessarily means it already rendered by the time you're referencing it in the code

Comment: You may want to consider a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in this case, especially for something like `select()`, `focus()`, etc. Keep in mind [select()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_select.asp) is for inputs like text.

Comment: @rubentd i have a function called `copyParams` which is where this code lives. It's defined in the container component and being passed to the child's `props`. Upon clicking the `Copy` button in the child component, it calls this function which executes this code, and i only get the `HTMLUnknownElement` after clicking that `Copy` button, so how come it hasn't been rendered yet?

Comment: I see... In this case it's safe to assume the element has already rendered.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, any chance you share more relevant code for this component?